# SuiteScript SO from RMA

Tags: return, authorization, suitescript

Looking for a place to start with this. NetSuite allows you to create a return authorization from a sales order but I'm looking to go the other way. Sales Order from a Return Authorization. Not a script writer, looking to understand how difficult this would be, and a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Suite Answer 45156](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45156/kw/45156#bridgehead_4327469981) transforming a record via SuiteScript from Return Authorization to Sales Order is not supported.  A potential workaround is to create a [Scheduled Script](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43798) or [Map/Reduce Script](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43795) (both execute according to schedule) or [Client Script](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43794) (execute on press of button).  To create a button use the Client Script type and [set the button from the UI on the script record page](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49306), or add the script to a specific form and create a [custom action/button](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49953).

use [N/search](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43702) module to search for RMAs 
use [N/record](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45152) module to create SO, set values, and save SO

outline:

```
require(['N/search'], function(search) {
  function loadAndRunSearch() {
    //create search in UI that identifies all of the RMAs or use search.create()
    var mySearch = search.load({
      id: 'customsearch_my_so_search'
    });

    //for each search result
    mySearch.run().each(function(result) {
      //get values
      var entity = result.getValue({name: 'entity'});
      var subsidiary = result.getValue({name: 'subsidiary'});
      //create SO
      var newSORec = record.create({
        type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER
      });
      //set values
      newSORec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'entity',
        value: entity
      });
      newSORec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'subsidiary',
        value: subsidiary
      });
      //save SO
      var newSORecId = newSORec.save();
      
    });
  }
  return {
    loadAndRunSearch: loadAndRunSearch
  }
});
```